# Set +x with fs.chmod

Tags: node.js, macos, permissions

My electronjs app needs to ensure that a proprietary binary dependency is executable on MacOS.

When I make my app run `fs.chmodSync('/pathToBinary', '+x')` it fails.

How can I make this work? How can I make my app set `+x` permissions to the proprietary binary?